# Can I make 'Edit-and-continue' = true the default for all new web projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, edit-and-continue

When creating a new web project in Visual Studio 2010 I always forget to enable 'Edit and Continue'  until it's "too late". (i.e. until I am editing while debugging and wish I was able to continue). So I would like "Edit & Continue" to be enabled by default.

The setting I'm referring to is under project properties, web tab, 'Debuggers' section. I've found that this setting isn't stored in the .csproj file, but in the .user file for the project, in a node called <EnableENC>. It is 'False' by default, but I wish it was 'True'.

(This applies equally well to VS2008 and perhaps 2005, but I only need to solve it for VS2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings in the .user file can be copied over to the .csproj file, therefore copy the setting in to the template .csproj file and [base a custom template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on it (or edit the common one somewhere in the Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio directory).

Comment: did you try your solution for this particular setting?